# Transform rows in columns

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have this table:

```
idSection   | idQuestion    | title     | enunciation | total   | name 
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1    | 5     | Good
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1    | 3     | Very Good
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1    | 1     | Bad
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2    | 1     | Good
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2    | 3     | Bad
1           | 3             | title 3   | question 3    | 1     | Bad
```

How can I make the column values **​​name** in multiple columns.

Here is the expected result:

```
title   | enunciantion  | bad   | good  | very good 
title 1 | question 1    | 1     | 5     | 3
title 2 | question 2    | 3     | 1     | 0
title 3 | question 3    | 1     | 0     | 0
```

I don't know how many columns there will be (it's dynamic).

**NEW EDIT:**

```
 title      |  enunciantion | Column0  | Column1 | Column2 | ... | Column7 |
   0        |   0           | bad      |  good   |very good| ... |    0    |
title 1     | question 1    | 1        | 5       | 3       | ... |    0    |
title 2     | question 2    | 3        | 1       | 0       | ... |    0    |
title 3     | question 3    | 1        | 0       | 0       | ... |    5    |
```

Now, the only difference is that instead of having dynamic columns, there are only static columns, however the first row of the table is such dynamic values ​​ranging look at another table.

Comment: You tagged this with both MySQL and SQL Server, what rdbms are you using?

Comment: @bluefeet Sorry, sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT
  title,
  enunciantion,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'bad' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS 'bad',
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'good' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS 'good',
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'very good ' THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS 'very good'
FROM Tablename
GROUP BY  title,
          enunciantion;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b864d/2)

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT
  title,
  enunciation,
  bad,
  good,
  [very good]
FROM Table1
PIVOT
(
  SUM(total) FOR name IN([good], [bad], [very good])
) p;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo<sup>SQL Server</sup>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b864d/3)

---

### Update:

If these values `good, bad, very good` are coming form another table and you want to do this dynamically.

For MySQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(Name = ''',
      Name, ''', Total, 0)) AS ',
      '''',Name, '''')
  ) INTO @sql
FROM names;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT title, enunciation, ',
                  @sql,
                  'FROM Table1 GROUP BY  title, '
                  '  enunciation; ');
prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo<sup>MySQL, dynamic</sup>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b864d/9)

```
|   TITLE | ENUNCIATION | GOOD | VERY GOOD | BAD | VERY BAD |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| title 1 |  question 1 |    5 |         3 |   1 |        0 |
| title 2 |  question 2 |    1 |         0 |   3 |        0 |
| title 3 |  question 3 |    0 |         0 |   1 |        0 |
```

---

For SQL Server you can do this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
                    from names c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT  title, enunciation, ' + @cols +
              ' FROM (SELECT title, enunciation, total, name
      FROM Table1) t
PIVOT
(
  SUM(total) FOR name IN( ' + @cols + + ' )) p;';

execute(@query);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo<sup>SQL Server, dynamic</sup>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46a1c/1)

This will give you:

```
|   TITLE | ENUNCIATION | BAD |   GOOD | VERY BAD | VERY GOOD |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| title 1 |  question 1 |   1 |      5 |   (null) |         3 |
| title 2 |  question 2 |   3 |      1 |   (null) |    (null) |
| title 3 |  question 3 |   1 | (null) |   (null) |    (null) |
```

Comment: i cant use the specific name, because it comes from other table and can be bad, good, very good or can be numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

Comment: If you say it comes from another table to do mean you want to insert into an new table? Then you need to do use the SQL query and use insert or update.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Ok, no problem. I've been searching on google and even using a single pivot. I think we are on the right track.

Comment: @sh0rt6r OK, I See my edit, I assumed that you have a table `names` that contained the names of these values.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal One more question, instead of appearing null, wanted to appear 0, i put isnull in SUM (total) but it gives the error "'ISNULL' is not Recognized the aggregate function."

Comment: @sh0rt6r see my answer that shows how to replace the `null` values.

Comment: @sh0rt6r Yes, As bluefeet pointed out, you have to do this in the dynamically concatenated list of columns, like in [**this updated version**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46a1c/5), or see [**blueefeets answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14258333/722783) below.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Here was to do some minor changes are needed and the names of the culunas would then be fixed (always seven (column 0, column 1, column 3, ..., column 7), however, the first row of the table, would be 0 for "title and enunciation" and the remaining columns would be "Good", "Very Good", etc ... the
However, it was getting, it is possible to help me? It is still possible, using this method?

Comment: @sh0rt6r - Sorry I don't understand, so, what is the desired output in this case? Currently it is `|   TITLE | ENUNCIATION | BAD |   GOOD | VERY BAD | VERY GOOD | .... etc` so what it should be? Thanks.

Comment: @sh0rt6r - So, the first row: `title      |  enunciantion | Column0  | Column1 | Column2 | ... | Column7 |` is coming from a table and the second row: `0        |   0           | bad      |  good   |very good| ... |    0    |` is coming from another table? and which one is static and which one is dynamic? if so please show these tables' structure? and sorry for my little understanding. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on [@Mahmoud Gamal's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257261/transform-rows-in-columns/14257367#14257367) answer on the dynamic SQL version for SQL server. If you want to replace the `null` values with zeros, then you can use the following:

```
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
                    from names c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull 
    = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ', 0) as '+ QUOTENAME(c.name)
             from names c
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT  title, enunciation, ' + @colsNull +
             ' FROM 
              (
                SELECT title, enunciation, total, name
                FROM results
              ) t
              PIVOT
              (
                  SUM(total) 
                  FOR name IN( ' + @colsPivot + + ' )
              ) p;';

exec(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d886/3)

The result is:

```
|   TITLE | ENUNCIATION | BAD | GOOD | VERY BAD | VERY GOOD |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| title 1 |  question 1 |   1 |    5 |        0 |         3 |
| title 2 |  question 2 |   3 |    1 |        0 |         0 |
| title 3 |  question 3 |   1 |    0 |        0 |         0 |
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal sure no problem, I figured I would show how to do it. :)

Comment: @sh0rt6r Is the code the same as what is above?  It is working on the demo --http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d886/3.

Comment: select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(nome) + ', 0) as '+ QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from iee WHERE scale=169 ORDER BY min
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

Comment: @sh0rt6r see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f3fb/5 -- change the second `name` to `nome` and place square brackets around the `min`