# SQL query inner join with 0 values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have this table:

```
idSection   | idQuestion    | title     | enunciation | idScale
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    3      
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    3      
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    3      
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    2
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    5
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2  |    1      
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2  |    3      
1           | 3             | title 3   | question 3  |    1
```

And have this table:

```
idScale   |       name 
   1      |      Very Bad
   2      |         Bad
   3      |         Good
   4      |      Very Good
   5      |      Excellent
```

I wanted a table like this:

```
idSection   | idQuestion    | title     | enunciation | Total  | Name
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    0   |  Very Bad
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    0   |  Bad
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    3   |  Good
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    0   |  Very Good
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    1   |  Excellent
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2  |    0   |  Very Bad
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2  |    1   |   Bad
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2  |    3   |  Good 
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2  |    0   |  Very Good
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2  |    0   |  Excellent
```

The query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.idSection, t1.idQuestion, t1.title, t1.enunciation, 
    COUNT(t1.idScale) as Total, t2.name 
FROM 
    table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 as t2 ON t2.idScale = t1.idScale
GROUP BY 
    t1.idSection, t1.idQuestion, t1.title, t1.enunciation, t2.name
```

The result of this is query:

```
idSection   | idQuestion    | title     | enunciation | Total  | Name
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    3   |  Good
1           | 1             | title 1   | question 1  |    1   |  Excellent
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2  |    1   |   Bad
1           | 2             | title 2   | question 2  |    3   |  Good
```

The problem with this is that query values ​​that are 0 don't appear.

Comment: where idEscalaEntrada field comes from?

Comment: @Bulat sorry copy paste problem... is idScale... i edited...

Comment: Did you try using a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: I would even say LEFT JOIN

Comment: Your second table doesn't have 0 so 0 doesn't appear in the select. Either add a 0 or use outer (left, right) join

Comment: @Bulat the Name value seems to come from t2, hence my suggestion for a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: @SchmitzIT t2 has less values in the key field then t1, that is why it should be LEFT

Comment: I don't want to be funny, but what is the difference between this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257261/transform-rows-in-columns and the current one. Have you change the server from SQL server to MySQL ;-) Back to the topic. Can we use the old SQLFIDDLE link to answer you question?

Comment: @Bulat - JOIN syntax has nothing to do with the amount of values, but it determines which table the non-matching rows are taken from.

Comment: @SchmitzIT you are right, I just did not understand the question correctly.

Comment: @Mr.Radical dont understand but ok...

Comment: Please, change tag from MySQL to SQL server

Comment: Can you provide us with a table(s) that will have all valid (idSection, idQuestion) combinations?

Comment: Guys enjoy: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7332c/2

Comment: @Bulat I dont understand but it is possible to have different idSection and idQuestion, which is why it is grouped

Comment: The problem is, that table1 might not have all possible combinations of idSection and idQuestion. As I understand your question, you what to have 0 for all combinations of (idSection, idQuestion) where it is not in table1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT
  t1.idSection,
  t1.idQuestion,
  t1.title,
  t1.enunciation, 
  SUM(case when t1.idScale=t2.idScale then 1 else 0 end) as Total,
  t2.name
FROM
  table1 AS t1, table2 as t2
GROUP BY t1.idSection, t1.idQuestion, t1.title, t1.enunciation, t2.name, t2.idScale
ORDER BY t1.idSection, t1.idQuestion, t2.idScale
```

this is not an INNER JOIN, but it's a cartesian join instead (every row of table1 is multiplied for every row of table2). I'm using SUM to count the rows where the INNER JOIN would have succeeded.

Comment: @sh0rt6r it was working, it should be okay, which error do you get? I 'll make a fiddle

Comment: @sh0rt6r sorry i thounght i've read mysql somewhere... fixed the answer, please see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7332c/4/0

Comment: @fthiella it was tagged sas mysql...before..long time no see mate :)

Comment: @bonCodigo :) :) nice to see you again :)

Comment: yes i put mysql tag but changed. i think this is exactly what i want.

Comment: Nice solution. The count not making it in had me stumped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(SELECT t1.idSection, t1.idQuestion, t1.title, t1.enunciation, 
   COUNT(t1.idScale) as Total, t2.name 
 FROM table1 t1
      JOIN table2 t2 
       ON t2.idScale=t1.idScale
GROUP BY t1.idSection, t1.idQuestion, t1.title, t1.enunciation, t2.name)
UNION 
 (SELECT DISTINCT 
  t1.idSection, idQuestion, title, enunciation, 0 as Total , t2.name
  FROM table1 t1,table2 t2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT  *
   FROM table1 
        JOIN table2 
         ON table2.idScale=table1.idScale
   WHERE t1.idSection = table1.idSection
     AND t1.idQuestion = table1.idQuestion
     AND t2.idScale= table2.idScale)
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7332c/15

Comment: Your querie has the same results as mine.

Comment: Added ISNULL as NULL values are not counted.

Comment: But i want to count, if you see my third table, very bad appear, however, in first table no.

Comment: @sh0rt6r changed the code basing on the assumption that you have all possible idSection and idQuestion combinations in Table1. In any case UNION is the only way I know to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.idSection, t1.idQuestion, t1.title, t1.enunciation, 
COUNT(t1.idScale) as Total, t2.name FROM table1 AS t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t2.idScale=t1.idScale
GROUP BY t1.idSection, t1.idQuestion, t1.title, t1.enunciation, t2.name
```

Comment: is almost. however, NULL appear me in idSection and idQuestion and I dont want. Want to appear for each id

Comment: you need to provide us with a separate table that will have all idSections and idQuestions. Then this type of queries can be solved with UNION

Comment: it is possible to have different idSection and idQuestion, which is why it is grouped