# sql join with not in column include in result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have two table like

```
id   Name    allocation
2    Ash      15
3    Alam     18
4    Rifat    20
```

and

```
Date   Id    Present
24     2     10
24     3     15
25     2     10
25     3     12
25     4     12
```

Now i want to get the following result

```
     Date  Id Alloc   Present
      24   2   15     10        
      24   3   18     15
      24   4   20     NULL
      25   2   15     10
      25   3   18     12
      25   4   20     12
```

I've tried `JOIN` query but it does not give desired result
How to get the above result?

Comment: rifat has not an entry in 2nd table.but i want to include him in result set as NULL or zero.every distinct date have right join to 1st table

Comment: somewhat similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317371/sql-querie-inner-join-with-0-values/14317831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.id
  , dd.date
  , t1.allocation
  , t2.present 
FROM 
    table1 AS t1                         --- all items
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT date
      FROM table2
    ) AS dd                              --- all dates
  LEFT JOIN
    table2 AS t2                         --- present allocations
      ON  t2.id = t1.id
      AND t2.date = dd.date ;
```

Tested at SQL-Fiddle: **[test](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2ded/18)** (thank you @JW.)

Comment: @njk: corrected (some commas were missing and table name had 2 l)

Comment: the problem with queries like this is that if Date value is missing for all items, it will not be shown in results. That is why it is better to have a separate table for Dates. Also your `OUTER JOIN` will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an interesting other way:

```
SELECT 
    t2.date,
    t1.id,
    t1.allocation,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t1.id = t2.id THEN t2.Present ELSE NULL END)
FROM 
    table1 t1, table2 t2
GROUP BY 
    t1.id, t2.date, t1.allocation
ORDER BY 
    t2.date, t1.id
```

Stolen from: [SQL query inner join with 0 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317371/sql-querie-inner-join-with-0-values/14317831)

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2ded/44

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Is that an ad of some blog? go ahead and post an answer with a `JOIN`.